# Why is the voltage the same before and after the diode in LTspice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, amplitude-modulation

In LTspice, I setup a circuit with a voltage generator giving a 160 kHz signal AM modulated with a 440 Hz signal and I'm trying to amplify this signal with a differential op amp.

[image]

Why is the voltage exactly the same before and after the diode D1 ?

Also why is the voltage before the diode the same as V(ANTENNNA-,ANTENNA+) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your circuit doesn't go anywhere, so the current through the diode is 0, and the diode's voltage drop is also zero.

Add a load (e.g. a resistor to ground) to the right of your AFTER node in order to make something useful happen.

Comment: Indeed, adding a 100 ohms resistor between after and ground makes a difference.
The peak voltage before is about 0.9mV and after it's about 350 nV.
But why, is that ?
Why I don't get the upper half of the signal before the diode rather than that ?

Comment: @Dong for the diode to have a voltage drop across it, a current must flow through it. In the reverse case, the current is tiny but not zero.

Comment: @Dong You should model your antenna as a current source, because what you have there is a voltage source across an inductor. If  it weren't for the default `Rser=1m`, you'd get an error.

Comment: @a concerned citizen, how do you create an AM modulated current source with the BI component ?